# How to change main user of domain in Dreamhost

Tags: wordpress, dreamhost

How can I change user of particular domain in https://www.dreamhost.com/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already checked the documentation? There are some useful explanations on https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215562847-One-user-per-domain-policy (and linked articles)